# Java 'System.err.format' with '%n' followed by 'System.out.println' , println prints in the middle

Tags: java, ubuntu

I am very new to Java.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, JDK 8u101, Netbeans8.1.

When trying this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.err.format("1st Line %nPrints At 3rd Line,Shouldn't this be In 2nd Line ");
    System.out.println("Shouldn't this be the third line,prints at 2nd line");
}
```

The output is:

```
This Prints At 1st Line 
Shouldn't this be the third line, but prints at 2nd line
This Prints At 3rd Line, Shouldn't this be In 2nd Line
```

Why does "`System.out.println`" print in the middle?
Shouldn't it print last.

I tried with "`%n`" at the end & `System.err.flush()` like this:

```
System.err.format("1st Line %nPrints At 3rd Line,Shouldn't this be In 2nd Line%n");
System.err.flush();
System.out.println("Shouldn't this be the third line,prints at 2nd line");
```

Still same output.

Comment: You are printing to two different streams, which are only flushed at the end of a line but System.err doesn't have a flush at the end of it's second line.

Answer (score 5):

You aren't calling [`flush()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#flush()) between the `println()` calls and `System.out` and `System.err` are both (*independently*) buffered `PrintStream`(s).

```
// and you need a %n on the end to make 3 lines.
System.err.format("1st Line %nPrints At 3rd Line,Shouldn't this be In 2nd Line%n"); 
System.err.flush(); // <-- only needed if the previous write doesn't have
                    //     an implicit flush(); newline (%n) does.
System.out.println("Shouldn't this be the third line,prints at 2nd line");
```

Comment: The `System.err` wasn't flushed because it didn't have a newline at the end. Thus you need a manual flush. +1 If you add %n, I don't think you also need a flush()

Comment: @PeterLawrey Correct. The Javadoc says *Optionally, a `PrintStream` can be created so as to flush automatically; this means that the `flush` method is automatically invoked after a byte array is written, one of the `println` methods is invoked, or a newline character or byte (`'\n'`) is written.*

Comment: I tried the code. I copy-pasted, saved, then run-ed again. I got the same output.

Comment: @Jit Recompile too.

Comment: I used "Clean and Build Project"  Still same output. Am I doing something wrong @Elliott Frisch